# An inequality for the derivative of Japanese bracket

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm reading a book that uses some properties of Japanese bracket. The author claims that, for any real number $m$ and multi-index $\beta$, it holds $$|\partial_x^\beta\langle x\rangle^m|\leq C^{|\beta|}\beta!\langle x\rangle^{m-|\beta|},$$ for some constant $C>0$ which doesn't depend on $\beta$.

I did some computations with some fix $m$, for example $m=1$ or $m=2$, etc., and assuming that $x\in\Bbb{R}$ (the property should be true for $\Bbb{R}^n$). But, by taking large $\beta\in\Bbb{N}$, the derivatives starts to get complicated (a lot of computations).

Does anybody know about a simple way to prove this inequality?

> Of course, we define $\langle x\rangle:=(1+|x|^2)^{1/2}$,

Answer (score 2):

If you allow me to ignore the constant...there is a simple way to prove this. First you prove the trivial

> Lemma: If $f:\Bbb R^n\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R$ is $A$-homogeneous, then $\partial^B f(x)$ is $(A-|B|)$-homogeneous.

Here, a function $f:\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R$ is $A$ homogeneous if for any $\lambda>0$, $f(\lambda x) = \lambda^A f(x)$.

From this, clearly in the 1D case $D^\beta|x|^m = m^{(\beta)}|x|^{m-|\beta|}$ times potentially $\operatorname{sgn} x$, where $m^{(\beta)}=m(m-1)\dots (m-\beta+1)$. In higher dimensions $n$ its not so clean but we end up with $\partial^\beta|x|^m =  f(x) $ where $f(x)$ is $(m-|\beta|)$-homogeneous.

Now observe $(t^2 + |x|^2)^{m/2}=|(t;x)|^{m}$ is $m$-homogeneous as a function on $\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$. Hence
$$ \partial^\beta_x |(t;x)|^{m} =  |(t;x)|^{m-|\beta|} f\left(\frac{(t;x)}{|(t;x)|}\right)$$

Setting $t=1$, we find
$$  \partial^\beta_x \langle x\rangle^{m} = \partial^\beta_x |1+|x|^2|^{m/2} =  |1+|x|^2|^{m/2-|\beta|/2} f\left(\frac{(1;x)}{\langle x \rangle }\right) \le C_{n,m,\beta} \langle x\rangle^{m-|\beta|},  $$

where $C_{n, m,\beta} = \sup_{y\in\mathbb R^{n+1}: |y|=1}|f(y)|$. QED.

Perhaps getting the constant after knowing the form of the inequality is not so hard but I don't have time at the moment to try...

Comment: This is so much simpler than what I've done haha (+1). Though I'm guessing you meant to put something other than "$1 + x^2$" in that last equation?

Comment: Well, I don't quite know what you would mean by $x^2$ for a vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is all.

Comment: Yes agreed just spotted. Will fix now :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to me like $C$ can be independent from $\beta$ when $m$ is not an even positive integer, or at the very least independent from $|\beta|$. In this answer I will explain briefly why I have that doubt (though I could be wrong!), and I will nonetheless prove something similar, which is that, for a given $m < 0$ (should be adaptable for $m$s which are not even positive integers):
$$\tag{1} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d,\,\forall \beta,\quad \left|\partial^\beta_x \langle x \rangle^m\right| \leq 2^{|\beta|}\left(- \frac{m}{2} + 2|\beta|\right)^{|\beta|} \beta! \langle x\rangle^{m - |\beta|}$$

For $m$ an even positive integer, $\langle x \rangle^m$ is simply a polynomial in $x$, but in that case the fix is easy, instead of $2^{|\beta|}\left(- \frac{m}{2} + 2|\beta|\right)^{|\beta|}$ you want to have $m^{|\beta|}$ in $(1)$ and that should do the trick.

First of all, you were somewhat in the right track: we'll first reduce the problem to the one variable case and then observe how that will give the result for several variables.
In order to make the latter doable however, we'll study the functions $x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto (a + x^2)^m$ for $a \geq 1$ instead of just $(1 + x^2)^m$ (I'm changing $m$ to what should be $2m$ in $(1)$ during this section, so as to not have to write $\frac{m}{2}$ everywhere). These functions are still well-defined and smooth, and have the exact same behaviour for their derivatives, but the main benefit to this approach lies in the fact that all the derivatives $\partial^\beta_x \langle x \rangle^{2m}$ will be linear combinations of that type of functions.
This is because, for each partial derivative along $x_j$, since you have:
$$\langle x \rangle^2 = 1 + x_1^2 + \cdots + x_{j-1}^2 + x_j^2 + x_{j+1}^2 + \cdots + x_d^2$$
you can set $1 + x_1^2 + \cdots + x_{j-1}^2 + x_{j+1}^2 + \cdots + x_d^2 \geq 1$ as your "$a$" and differentiate $x_j \mapsto \left(a + x_j^2\right)^m$. Luckily, the expression of the derivatives can then be expressed with only coefficients which are constant (in regards to $x$), $x_j$, and terms of the form $\left(a + x_j^2\right)^{m - l}$, but $a + x_j^2$ is just $\langle x \rangle^2$, and so that procedure can then be repeated in the same fashion along the other variables.

After writing out the first few derivatives manually (which I will not do here), and using the information in what's desired in $(1)$ for one variable, one can claim the following lemma is true for a given $m < 0$ (I'll use the convention $(-1)! := 1$ to handle $k = 0$ like the others):

> Lemma: Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, there exist two finite sequences $(u_{k,i})_{0 \leq i \leq k}$ and $(v_{k,i})_{0 \leq i \leq k}$ such that, for all $a \geq 1$:
> \begin{align*} \tag{2a}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2k}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2k}}\left(a + x^2\right)^m &= \sum_{i = 0}^{k} u_{k,i} \,x^{2i} \left(a+x^2\right)^{m - k - i}\\ \tag{2b}
> \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2k+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2k+1}}\left(a + x^2\right)^m &= \sum_{i = 0}^{k} v_{k,i} \,x^{2i+1} \left(a+x^2\right)^{m - k - i - 1}
> \end{align*}
> and such that, for all $0 \leq i \leq k$:
> \begin{align*} |u_{k,i}| &\leq 2^{2k} (2k - 1)! \prod_{j = 0}^{2k-1} (-m + j)\\ |v_{k,i}| &\leq 2^{2k+1} (2k)! \prod_{j = 0}^{2k} (-m + j)
> \end{align*}

The fact the $u_{k,i}$s and $v_{k,i}$s are uniformly bounded in regard to $i$ is important.

Let's prove this lemma by induction: for $k = 0$ we have the conclusion if we take $u_{0,0} = 1$ and $v_{0,0} = 2m$, thus we can focus on the induction.
Assume the lemma's result is true for a fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let's show it remains true for $k+1$.
Let $(u_{k,i})_{0 \leq i \leq k}$ and $(v_{k,i})_{0 \leq i \leq k}$ be the sequences from the statement of the lemma.
$(2\mathrm{b})$ can be differentiated to obtain what follows:
$$\begin{split}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2k+2}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2k+2}}\left(a + x^2\right)^m &= \sum_{i = 0}^{k} v_{k,i} \,(2i+1)x^{2i} \left(a+x^2\right)^{m - k - i - 1}\\
&\quad + \sum_{i = 0}^{k} v_{k,i} \,x^{2i+1} \cdot 2(m - k - i - 1)x\left(a+x^2\right)^{m - k - i - 2}\\
&= v_{k,0}\left(a+x^2\right)^{m-k-1}\\
&\quad+ \sum_{i = 1}^{k} \left((2i+1)v_{k,i} + (m - k - i)v_{k,i-1}\right) x^{2i} \left(a+x^2\right)^{m - k - i - 1}\\
&\quad + 2(m-2k-1) v_{k,k}\,x^{2k+2}\left(a+x^2\right)^{m - 2k - 2}\\
&=: \sum_{i = 0}^{k+1} u_{k+1,i} \,x^{2i} \left(a+x^2\right)^{m - (k + 1) - i} \quad (\dagger)
\end{split}$$
We then have, for $1 \leq i \leq k$ (for $k = 0$, there is no such $i$):
$$\begin{split} |u_{k+1,i}| &\leq |v_{k,i}| (2i+1) + 2|v_{k,i-1}| |m - k - i|\\
&\leq |v_{k,i}| (2k+1)|m - 2k - 1| + (2k+1)|v_{k,i-1}||m - 2k - 1|\\ &\quad\quad\quad\text{thanks to $2 \leq 2k+1$ when $k \geq 1$, and $m < 0$}\\
&\leq 2(2k+1)(-m+2k+1) \cdot 2^{2k+1} (2k)! \prod_{j = 0}^{2k} (-m + j)\\
&\leq 2^{2k+2} (2k+1)! \prod_{j = 0}^{2k+1} (-m + j)\end{split}$$
And for $i = 0$ and $i = k+1$ the same estimate holds.
Afterwards, I'll hope you trust that $(\dagger)$ can be differentiated to get the other derivative and the sequence $(v_{k+1,i})$ in the same vein.

This means that the lemma is true for $k+1$ when it is true for $k$, and it holds for $k = 0$, thus by induction it is true for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

The reason why I doubt that $C$ will be independent on $\beta$ is due to the fact that differentiating $\left(a + x^2\right)^m$ repeatedly introduces that $m(m-1)\cdots(m-k)$ term on all the terms of the "polynomial" expression (with more or less factors), and I find it hard to believe that for $m$ not an integer this can be controlled "well" with just a constant to the power $|\beta|$...

Now, the calculations get more complicated due to the multi-indices from this point onwards, and I don't really want to write out *everything* (for my sake and yours), but essentially, by induction on the coordinates of $\beta$ or $x$ (differentiating along each $x_j$) and by exhaustion of cases (depending on the even or odd trait of the number of derivatives taken), the derivatives $\partial^\beta_x \langle x \rangle^m$ will be of the form below:
$$\tag{3} \partial^\beta_x \langle x \rangle^{2m} = \sum_{(i_1, \dots, i_d) \atop 0\leq i_j \leq \beta_j} \left(\prod_{j = 1}^{d} w^{\left(m - \left(\sum_{s = 1}^{j-1} \beta_s + i_s\right)\right)}_{\beta_j, i_j} x_j^{i_j}\right) \langle x \rangle^{2m - \left(\sum_{j = 1}^{d} \beta_j + 2i_j + \varepsilon_j\right)}$$
where $\varepsilon_j = \begin{cases}0 \quad \text{if } \beta_j = 2k\\ 1 \quad \text{if } \beta_j = 2k+1\end{cases}$ and the previous lemma is used to create the sequences $\left(w^{(m')}_{\beta_j,i}\right)_{0 \leq i \leq 2k+1}$ for all $m' < 0$ and all $1 \leq j \leq d$ such that:
$$\left|w^{(m')}_{\beta_j,i}\right| \leq 2^{\beta_j} (\beta_j - 1)! \prod_{l = 0}^{\beta_j} (-m' + l)$$
and
$$\tag{$\top$}\left(w^{(m')}_{2k, 2i+1}\right)_i = (0)_i \quad\underline{\mathrm{and}}\quad \left(w^{(m')}_{2k+1, 2i}\right)_i = (0)_i$$

It's almost over. Consider a fixed $d$-tuple $(i_1, \dots, i_d)$. Due to the fact that $\langle x \rangle \geq 1$ and that $|y| = \left(y^2\right)^\frac{1}{2} \leq \left(a + y^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$ for $a \geq 0$, we get:
$$\left|\prod_{j = 1}^d x_j^{i_j}\right| \langle x \rangle^{2m - \left(\sum_{j = 1}^{d} \beta_j + 2i_j + \varepsilon_j\right)} \leq \langle x \rangle^{\sum_{j = 1}^{d} i_j} \langle x \rangle^{2m - \left(\sum_{j = 1}^{d} \beta_j + 2i_j + \varepsilon_j\right)} \leq \langle x \rangle^{2m - |\beta|}$$
Furthermore:
$$\begin{split}\prod_{j = 1}^{d} \left|w^{\left(m - \left(\sum_{s = 1}^{j-1} \beta_s + i_s\right)\right)}_{\beta_j, i_j}\right| &\leq \prod_{j = 1}^d \left(2^{\beta_j} (\beta_j - 1)! \prod_{l = 0}^{\beta_j} \left(- m + \left(\sum_{s = 1}^{j - 1} \underbrace{\beta_s + i_s}_{\leq\, 2\beta_s}\right) + \underbrace{l}_{\leq\, 2\beta_j}\right)\right)\\
&\leq 2^{|\beta|} \prod_{j = 1}^d \left((\beta_j - 1)! \prod_{l = 0}^{\beta_j} \left(- m + \sum_{s = 1}^{j} 2\beta_s\right)\right)\\
&\leq 2^{|\beta|} \prod_{j = 1}^d \left((\beta_j - 1)! \prod_{l = 0}^{\beta_j} \left(- m + 2|\beta|\right)\right)\\
&\leq 2^{|\beta|} \left(\prod_{j = 1}^d (\beta_j - 1)!\right) \left(- m + 2|\beta|\right)^{|\beta|}\end{split}$$

Therefore we can finally conclude, after inserting these inequalities into $(3)$ and using the triangle inequality:
$$\begin{split}\left|\partial^\beta_x \langle x \rangle^{2m}\right| &\leq \sum_{{(i_1, \dots, i_d) \atop 0\leq i_j \leq \beta_j} \atop \forall m' < 0,\,\, w^{(m')}_{\beta_j, i_j} \neq 0} 2^{|\beta|} \left(\prod_{j = 1}^d (\beta_j - 1)!\right) \left(- m + 2|\beta|\right)^{|\beta|} \langle x \rangle^{2m - |\beta|}\\
&\leq \overbrace{\operatorname{Card}\left\{(i_1, \dots, i_d) \mid 0 \leq i_j \leq \beta_j,\,\, \forall m' < 0,\,\, w^{(m')}_{\beta_j, i_j} \neq 0\right\}}^{=: \,\,C_{m,\beta}}\\
&\quad \cdot 2^{|\beta|} \left(\prod_{j = 1}^d (\beta_j - 1)!\right) \left(- m + 2|\beta|\right)^{|\beta|} \langle x \rangle^{2m - |\beta|}\end{split}$$
The third condition on the sum is there to be able to use $(\top)$, and say that, for each $\beta_j \neq 0$, there is about half, and so at least one, of the $i_j$s such that $w^{(m')}_{\beta_j, i_j} = 0$, therefore $C_{m,\beta} \leq \prod_{j = 1}^d \max(1, \beta_j)$ (accounting for the $j$s such that $\beta_j = 0$), hence:
$$\begin{split} \left|\partial^\beta_x \langle x \rangle^{2m}\right| &\leq \prod_{j = 1}^d \max(1, \beta_j)\cdot 2^{|\beta|} \left(\prod_{j = 1}^d (\beta_j - 1)!\right) \left(- m + 2|\beta|\right)^{|\beta|} \langle x \rangle^{2m - |\beta|}\\
&\leq 2^{|\beta|} \left(\prod_{j = 1}^d \beta_j!\right) \left(- m + 2|\beta|\right)^{|\beta|} \langle x \rangle^{2m - |\beta|}\\
&\leq 2^{|\beta|} \left(- m + 2|\beta|\right)^{|\beta|} \beta! \langle x \rangle^{2m - |\beta|}\end{split}$$
Changing $m$ into $\frac{m}{2}$ then provides $(1)$, and we are done (phew!).

I am aware I did not really make this answer as simple as you or I would have liked, but I don't quite know if there is really a way to make inequalities revolving around derivatives and multi-indices "simple"...